# Committing transaction outside of stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

When doing 1 or more stored procedures, can you place a transaction around the procedure instead of inside of it?

```
$db->beginTransaction();

$db->exec("call my_procedure()");
$db->exec("call my_second_procedure()");

$db->commit();
```

When doing the above (`pdo`), does the transaction commit after both calls, or does it auto commit after each call is run making `beginTransaction()` and `commit()` useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

As long as none of the procedures executes a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` or `START TRANSACTION` internally, and as long as none of the procedures (or your code) executes any of the [statements that cause an implicit commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/implicit-commit.html), this works fine.

Autocommit is not in effect while you have a transaction running, even though `SELECT @@autocommit;` will still indicate "1," which is only an indication that your *session* is in autocommit mode when a transaction isn't active.

Comment: I hope this works, because it seems technically feasible according to the documentation. But, I would urge testing to see if your database is consistent when something fails. For instance, doing `INSERTS` with multiple tables, using multiple stored procedures (which may themselves have embedded `PREPARE`, `EXECUTE`, and `DEALLOCATE PREPARE` statements) called from PHP PDO, might not actually work after all. But, testing is my point. Testing.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge one problem with the original question is that `$db->exec()` apparently doesn't actually throw an exception when the database throws an error; apparently you have to manually check `PDO::errorInfo()`.  So the code "works" but is not safe in the sense that it just keeps on rolling if one of the procs throws an error... but the idea is valid.  I have a proc called `mysql.require_transaction()` that I call from inside other procs, causing them to fail early if they find themselves running on a thread without an active transaction, for whatever reason.

Comment: I use PDO prepared statements to call my stored procedures. Also, I set the PDO error mode to `ERRORMODE_EXCEPTION`. Then, I start my transactions within a `try/catch` block.

Comment: That's good. But, unless PDO is going to the trouble to detect and avoid letting you do it (there's a bit flag on the wire protocol that can be tested, but libraries never seem to use it), it is still problematic that MySQL doesn't throw an error if you rollback while you aren't in a transaction, and starting a transaction while already in a transaction is treated by MySQL as equivalent to issuing `COMMIT AND CHAIN`, silently committing the previous transaction and starting a new one.  Both of these are deep rooted design mistakes from years ago, presumably too entrenched to fix.

Comment: @sqlbot The transaction nesting thing is in the manual. That's nothing new. Forget the `exec()` method for a second. The way I use PDO with `PDO::prepare()`, `PDO::execute()` etc within a `try/catch` block ... works.

Comment: I am, of course, aware that it is documented; I mention it because it seems to escape many people's attention all the same.

Answer (score -1):

I would say, "it depends" :-)

first of all, if you are using MyISAM, which does not support transaction, `PDO::beginTransaction()` still returns true, but no transaction started.

See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php